# How can I exclude Spin Buttons from my Excel sheet protection?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007. I need to exclude [Spin Buttons](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/add-a-scroll-bar-or-spin-button-to-a-worksheet-HP010236682.aspx#BMadd_or_edit_a_spinner_(forms_toolbar)) from my Excel sheet's protection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is "spinner"?

Comment: The buttons with the arrows, http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/qSt2va3TvP0/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy.

- Unprotect your sheet.
- Unlock the cell the Spin Box is linked to.
- Protect the sheet again.

More info: [Lock or unlock specific areas of a protected worksheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-HA010096837.aspx)